# Product autocomplete input on module (Prestashop)

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I'm developing a prestashop module that has to make lists of existing products.

For the configuration panel of the module, using *renderForm()* and *getContent()*, I'm trying to replicate the "accesories" capability, where you start writing some info of a product on an input, and it shows the products that are a match. When selecting that product, it gets added on a list. Like this:

[image: prestashop accessoreies form]

This a screenshot of Catalog / Products / Associations tab.

I'm trying with PS 1.6.0.14 and PS1.6.1.0RC3. How would I replicate this functionality to get lists of products on a module configuration panel?

I tried looking here [Prestashop AdminProductsController.php](https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/blob/1.6/controllers/admin/AdminProductsController.php#L2735) but I don't really understand where half of that info is coming from.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that to achieve that functionality, the renderForm() function won't be enough since you have to bind some javascript and some custom html.

The process of writing a fully functional module is a bit long but by taking the accessories functionality as a starting point it wont be so hard and you will always have a reference on "how-to-do-it".
I would go with this:

1) first create your

> getContent()

function to be able to show the custom template and the product associated by your module so we will have something along:

```
    public function getContent(){

    //post process part to save the associations
    if(Tools::isSubmit('saveMyAssociations'){
     ... //we will see it later
    }

    $my_associations = MyModule::getAssociationsLight($this->context->language->id,Tools::getValue('id_product')); //function that will retrieve the array of all the product associated on my module table.

     $this->context->smarty->assign(array(
                    'my_associations' => $my_associations,
                    'product_id' => (int)Tools::getValue('id_product')
                ));

    return $this->display(__FILE__, 'views/templates/admin/admintemplate.tpl'); //custome template to create the autocomplete

    }

//our little function to get the already saved list, for each product we will retrieve id, name and reference with a join on the product/product_lang tables.
 public static function getAssociationsLight($id_lang, $id_product, Context $context = null)
    {
        if (!$context)
            $context = Context::getContext();

        $sql = 'SELECT p.`id_product`, p.`reference`, pl.`name`
                FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'my_associations`
                LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'product` p ON (p.`id_product`= `id_product_2`)
                '.Shop::addSqlAssociation('product', 'p').'
                LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'product_lang` pl ON (
                    p.`id_product` = pl.`id_product`
                    AND pl.`id_lang` = '.(int)$id_lang.Shop::addSqlRestrictionOnLang('pl').'
                )
                WHERE `id_product_1` = '.(int)$id_product;

        return Db::getInstance()->executeS($sql);
    }
```

2) create a template that will be able to show the automplete and the list.
Here we will loop trough the saved associations to create our autocomplete list, and we will do it with some hidden field to keep track of the ids/name and also a visible list were we will have a delete button for each row.

```
        <input type="hidden" name="inputMyAssociations" id="inputMyAssociations" value="{foreach from=$my_associations item=accessory}{$accessory.id_product}-{/foreach}" />
        <input type="hidden" name="nameMyAssociations" id="nameMyAssociations" value="{foreach from=$my_associations item=accessory}{$accessory.name|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}¤{/foreach}" />
        <div id="ajax_choose_product_association">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" id="product_autocomplete_input_association" name="product_autocomplete_input_association" />
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="icon-search"></i></span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="divMyAssociations">
            {foreach from=$my_associations item=accessory}
                <div class="form-control-static">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default delAssociation" name="{$accessory.id_product}">
                        <i class="icon-remove text-danger"></i>
                    </button>
                    {$accessory.name|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}{if !empty($accessory.reference)}{$accessory.reference}{/if}
                </div>
            {/foreach}
        </div>
    <input type="submit" name="submitMyAssociations" id="submitMyAssociations" value="Send"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="productId" id="productId" value="{$product_id|escape:'html'}"/>
```

3) Now we can add the javascript to bind an autocomplete on the main input and perform all the logic for each action

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
//our function wrapper.
            var initMyAssociationsAutocomplete = function (){
//initialize the autocomplete that will point to the default ajax_products_list page (it returns the products by id+name)
                $('#product_autocomplete_input_association')
                        .autocomplete('ajax_products_list.php', {
                            minChars: 1,
                            autoFill: true,
                            max:20,
                            matchContains: true,
                            mustMatch:true,
                            scroll:false,
                            cacheLength:0,
                            formatItem: function(item) {
                                return item[1]+' - '+item[0];
                            }
                        }).result(addAssociation);
    //as an option we will add a function to exclude a product if it's already in the list
                $('#product_autocomplete_input_association').setOptions({
                    extraParams: {
                        excludeIds : getAssociationsIds()
                    }
                });
            };
    //function to exclude a product if it exists in the list
            var getAssociationsIds = function()
            {
                if ($('#inputMyAssociations').val() === undefined)
                    return '';
                return $('#inputMyAssociations').val().replace(/\-/g,',');
            }
    //function to add a new association, adds it in the hidden input and also as a visible div, with a button to delete the association any time.
            var addAssociation = function(event, data, formatted)
            {
                if (data == null)
                    return false;
                var productId = data[1];
                var productName = data[0];

                var $divAccessories = $('#divCrossSellers');
                var $inputAccessories = $('#inputMyAssociations');
                var $nameAccessories = $('#nameMyAssociations');

                /* delete product from select + add product line to the div, input_name, input_ids elements */
                $divAccessories.html($divAccessories.html() + '<div class="form-control-static"><button type="button" class="delAssociation btn btn-default" name="' + productId + '"><i class="icon-remove text-danger"></i></button>&nbsp;'+ productName +'</div>');
                $nameAccessories.val($nameAccessories.val() + productName + '¤');
                $inputAccessories.val($inputAccessories.val() + productId + '-');
                $('#product_autocomplete_input_association').val('');
                $('#product_autocomplete_input_association').setOptions({
                    extraParams: {excludeIds : getAssociationsIds()}
                });
            };
    //the function to delete an associations, delete it from both the hidden inputs and the visible div list.
            var delAssociations = function(id)
            {
                var div = getE('divMyAssociations');
                var input = getE('inputMyAssociations');
                var name = getE('nameMyAssociations');

                // Cut hidden fields in array
                var inputCut = input.value.split('-');
                var nameCut = name.value.split('¤');

                if (inputCut.length != nameCut.length)
                    return alert('Bad size');

                // Reset all hidden fields
                input.value = '';
                name.value = '';
                div.innerHTML = '';
                for (i in inputCut)
                {
                    // If empty, error, next
                    if (!inputCut[i] || !nameCut[i])
                        continue ;

                    // Add to hidden fields no selected products OR add to select field selected product
                    if (inputCut[i] != id)
                    {
                        input.value += inputCut[i] + '-';
                        name.value += nameCut[i] + '¤';
                        div.innerHTML += '<div class="form-control-static"><button type="button" class="delAssociation btn btn-default" name="' + inputCut[i] +'"><i class="icon-remove text-danger"></i></button>&nbsp;' + nameCut[i] + '</div>';
                    }
                    else
                        $('#selectAssociation').append('<option selected="selected" value="' + inputCut[i] + '-' + nameCut[i] + '">' + inputCut[i] + ' - ' + nameCut[i] + '</option>');
                }

                $('#product_autocomplete_input_association').setOptions({
                    extraParams: {excludeIds : getAssociationsIds()}
                });
            };

    //finally initialize the function we have written above and create all the binds.
                initMyAssociationsAutocomplete();
//live delegation of the deletion button to our delete function, this will allow us to delete also any element added after the dom creation with the ajax autocomplete.
                $('#divMyAssociations').delegate('.delAssociation', 'click', function(){
                    delAssociations($(this).attr('name'));
                });
         });
```

4) now you just need to save the associations made by your module autocomplete, and i suggest to perform it by first deleting any association made on a given product and then saving all of them. so you don't have to care about inserting or updating an entry

```
public function getContent(){

//post process part
if(Tools::isSubmit('saveMyAssociations'){

       $product_id = (int)Tools::getValue('productId');
// see the function below, a simple query to delete all the associations on a product
            $this->deleteMyAssociations($product_id);
            if ($associations = Tools::getValue('inputMyAssociations'))
            {
                $associations_id = array_unique(explode('-', $associations));
                if (count($associations_id))
                {
                    array_pop($associations_id);
                   //insert all the association we have made.
                    $this->changeMyAssociations($associations_id, $product_id);

                }
            }
}

}

protected function deleteMyAssociations($product_id){
return Db::getInstance()->execute('DELETE FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'my_associations` WHERE `id_product_1` = '.(int)$product_id);
}

protected function changeMyAssociations($associations_id, $product_id){
        foreach ($associations_id as $id_product_2)
            Db::getInstance()->insert('my_associations', array(
                'id_product_1' => (int)$product_id,
                'id_product_2' => (int)$id_product_2
            ));
}
```

I hope it can help you to go through all of this.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I've been busy with another project and this one suffered a lot of delays.

Thanks a lot for the lengthy response. In the next few days I'm going to try and figure it out.

Comment: The only thing your perfect explanation lacked was that you've used "my asociations" table on the database, without saying that you have to create that if not exists whenever you "install" the module.

Answer (score 5):

There is an autocomplete plugin in prestashop you got to use that for this. Its in js->jquery->plugins you got to add this plugin into your module to make it work.

Comment: But how? Teach me master.

Comment: Teach us sensei